# Why can't I build after adding Mercurial project to Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, mercurial, build, javac

I got my eclipse project set up with Mercurial so that I could code with some friends. I'm having a bit of a problem where Eclipse won't build my project anymore! The build project option in the build menu is grayed out. What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright so I found my answer, it took some sneakiness with the .project file. I needed to add a Java builder after changing the project to a Java project. Add these lines to your .project file to fix the problem:

```
<buildSpec>
    <buildCommand>
        <name>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder</name>
        <arguments>
        </arguments>
    </buildCommand>
</buildSpec>
```